# How use jQuery to append a element to the right side of another element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have

```
<input type='text', id='name'></input>
```

and I have

```
<p>my name is xyz</p>
```

I would like the `<p>` element to be located 20px the right side of `<input>`, how to use **jQuery** to achieve this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('<p></p>').html('my name is xyz').css('margin-left', '20px').insertAfter($('#name'));
```

or

```
$('/*select p*/').css({'margin-left':'20px'}).after($('#name'));
```

Or just put css

```
p{
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```